# Why did this plant lose its red flowers?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, flowering

I purchased this plant, and I don’t remember the name. At the time it had one or two vividly red, waxy flowers. The flower had a “tongue” part (excuse my ignorance) that looks like a hard, bumpy capsule?

Anyway, the flowers lasted for at least a year. During that time, they remained extremely red and sturdy (they almost looked fake). Eventually, they died. The plant itself seems to do fine even when deprived of water and light for several weeks. For the last several months, I’ve kept it exposed to lots of light and water it when the soil is dry. But it has never produced another flower. Sometimes a shoot of what **might** be a flower has grown out but is almost immediately brown and dried.

[image]

1. Does anyone have any idea what this plant is called? For some reason, I want to say that its colloquial name had the word “lady” in it, but I might be dead wrong.
2. Why did the flowers die after being fine for over a year? Is there anything I need to do to get it to bloom again (perhaps in the spring since fall is coming up where I live.)

I have kept it exclusively indoors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an anthurium.  Their flowers are waxy and last a long time but not forever.

I recommend removing the white pebbles on the surface. The most common cause of houseplant problems is overwatering. When you can see the soil you are in a better position to water when needed.

Provide bright diffuse light in a cool area. Do not repot. Fertilize monthly at 1/4 strength with flowering plant fertilizer. Something like a 10 30 10.

Fungus gnats can be controlled by keeping the top of the soil dryer, using sticky strips or, surprisingly, sprinkling cinnamon on the surface.

Comment: Thank you! So I should remove the pebbles? I originally put those in all my plants because I had a problem with gnats. I heard I could help suffocate them with a soil topper like pebbles. But I’ll remove them.

Comment: gnats indicate a wetter than usual soil.

Comment: @cifilter The gnats are probably smaller than the gapes in the pebbles, so not terribly effective. A thin layer of grit/sharp  sand would be more effective, but will eventually mix into the soil.

Comment: @CIFilter edited my answer to address fungus gnats

Comment: Thanks for the update! I added a very thick layer of diatomaceous Earth on all my other pots and that seems to have gotten rid of the vast majority. I may sprinkle cinnamon on this smaller plant!